# Protobuf-net surrogate class for BigInteger

Tags: c#, biginteger, protobuf-net

I want protobuf-net on BigInteger values.
So, I write surrogate class, test and got result

This is source for test:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace BigIntegerSurrogate
{
    [ProtoContract]
    public class AA
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public BigInteger Bi { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class BigIntegerSurrogate
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public byte[] BigIntegerBytes;

        [ProtoConverter]
        public static BigIntegerSurrogate Convert(BigInteger source)
        {
            var t = source.ToByteArray();
            Console.WriteLine($"Convert from Source: {source.ToString()} =>     [{string.Join(",", t)}]");

            return new BigIntegerSurrogate
            {
                BigIntegerBytes = t
            };
        }

        [ProtoConverter]
        public static BigInteger Convert(BigIntegerSurrogate surrogate)
        {
            if (surrogate == null || surrogate.BigIntegerBytes == null)
            {
                return BigInteger.Zero;
            }
            else
            {
                var bi = new BigInteger(surrogate.BigIntegerBytes);
                Console.WriteLine($"Convert from Bytes: [{string.Join(",",     surrogate.BigIntegerBytes)}] => {bi.ToString()}");
                return bi;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var model = ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
            //model.Add(typeof(BigInteger), true);
            model.Add(typeof(BigInteger),     false).SetSurrogate(typeof(BigIntegerSurrogate));

            var aa = new AA() { Bi = 100 };

            byte[] aaSerialized;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(stream, aa);
                aaSerialized = stream.ToArray();
            }

            AA aa2;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(aaSerialized))
            {
                aa2 = Serializer.Deserialize<AA>(stream);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{aa2.Bi.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

This is result:

```
Convert from Source: 100 => [100]
Convert from Source: 0 => [0]
Convert from Bytes: [0,100] => 25600
```

First, protobuf calls on expected value (=100), but it calls again with unknown zero.

And it calls convert() on deserialization with concatinated array of 100 and 0.
So, result value is wrong.

Do I something wrong? If so, what's the correct way to (de)serialize BigInteger with binary format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the second convert is the initial value during deserialization, and this is then causing a concatenated byte array. One quick fix might be to check for zero in the conversion operator and always assign a null/empty byte array. This will concatenate cleanly. However, the "correct" fix is probably to add the "overwrite list" flag in the `ProtoMemberAttibute` on the byte array - this will ensure that the contents are replaced rather than concatenated. I'd be tempted to do both of these together, frankly.

Comment: I tried with [ProtoMember(1, OverwriteList = true)] on BigIntegerBytes and it works. Thank you!!