# Converting a BigInteger array to a byte array and back in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption, cryptography, biginteger

#### Problem

I have a `BigInteger` array which I'm converting to a byte array as:

```
var ciphertext = new BigInteger[ciphertextBlocks];
...
byte[] ciphertextBytes = ciphertext.SelectMany(c => c.ToByteArray()).ToArray();
```

Now, I would like to get the original `BigInteger` array back. This seems impossible since the individual sizes of each `BigInteger` is lost when it is converted to `byte[]`.

#### Context

I understand this could very well be an XY problem. Therefore, here's what I'm doing. I'm implementing a simple cryptosystem called [Merkle-Hellman Knapsack Cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem) for encryption and decryption.

*I know that rolling your own cryptographic algorithms is [frowned upon](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209652/why-is-it-wrong-to-implement-myself-a-known-published-widely-believed-to-be) but I'm doing it purely for educational purposes.*

Since the output of a cryptographic operation is represented as `byte[]`, I'm converting the resultant ciphertext (`BigInteger[]`) to a `byte[]` in `Encrypt()`).

However, I need access to the original `BigInteger[]` array in the `Decrypt()` method to individually decrypt each `BigInteger`. Is there a way to achieve this in the `Decrypt()` method?

If the type were a fixed-size primitive like `long`, I could do something like this:

```
long[] cipherTextInt = new long[ciphertext.Length / sizeof(long)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(ciphertext, 0, cipherTextInt, 0, ciphertext.Length);
```

But since `BigInteger` can be arbitrarily large, how can this be done?

```
public class KnapsackCryptosystem
{
    const int BitsPerByte = 8;
    
    public PublicKeyInfo PublicKey { get; }

    private PrivateKeyInfo PrivateKey { get; }

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plaintext)
    {

        var plaintextBits = new BitArray(plaintext);
        var sequence = PublicKey.Sequence;
        
        // Calculate number of ciphertext blocks:
        // Dividing the length of the sequence by the bit length of the plaintext gives
        // the number of ciphertext blocks. If the plaintext bit length is not a multiple of 
        // the sequence length (remainder != 0), an extra block is required.
        var (quotient, remainder) = Math.DivRem(plaintextBits.Count, sequence.Count);
        var ciphertextBlocks = quotient + (remainder == 0 ? 0 : 1);

        // Create a BigInteger array to hold the ciphertext integers
        var ciphertext = new BigInteger[ciphertextBlocks];

        // Apply the sequence to each plaintext block
        for (int i = 0; i < ciphertextBlocks; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sequence.Count; j++)
            {
                // Calculate the end index of the current block
                int endIndex = (i + 1) * sequence.Count;
                // Calculate the index of the jth bit from the end; 
                int bitIndex = end - j - 1;

                try
                {
                    var bit = plaintextBits[bitIndex];
                    //Console.WriteLine($"j={j} : idx={rIndex} : bit={(bit ? 1 : 0)} | ");
                    Console.WriteLine($"j={j} : idx={index} : bit={(bit ? 1 : 0)} : ");
                    if (bit)
                    {
                        // Add the jth element to the ith ciphertext block if the bit is set
                        Console.WriteLine($"+{sequence[j]} .");
                        ciphertext[i] += sequence[j];
                    }
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    // thrown at the last block when the sequence length exceeds the last plaintext block
                    Console.WriteLine(nameof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException) + " " + index);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Ciphertext Elements:");
        Array.ForEach(ciphertext, x => Console.WriteLine(x));

        // Convert the BigInteger[] array to byte[]
        var ciphertextBytes = ciphertext.SelectMany(c => c.ToByteArray()).ToArray(); 
        return ciphertextBytes;
    }


    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] ciphertext)
    {
        var sequence = PrivateKey.Sequence;
        int wInverse = ModularArithmetic.MultiplicativeInverse(PrivateKey.W, PrivateKey.M);
        Console.WriteLine($"wInverse: {wInverse}");

        // RESTORE BigInteger[] FROM byte[] ciphertext. How to achieve this?
        // cipherTextInts is the restored BigInteger array containing the ciphertext for each block
        var ciphertextInts = BACK_TO_BIG_INTEGER_ARRAY(ciphertext);
        var plaintextBits = new BitArray(<UNKNOWN_LENGTH>);


        for (int i = 0; i < ciphertextInts.Length; i++)
        {
            var ciphertextElement = (wInverse * ciphertextInts[i]) % PrivateKey.M;

            // Solve the subset sum problem
            for (int j = PrivateKey.Sequence.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (PrivateKey.Sequence[j] <= ciphertextElement)
                {
                    // Calculate the end index of the current block
                    int endIndex = (i + 1) * sequence.Count;
                    // Calculate the index of the jth bit from the end; 
                    int bitIndex = end - j - 1;

                    plaintextBits[bitIndex] = true;
                    ciphertextElement -= PrivateKey.Sequence[j];
                    //Console.WriteLine($"    Minus {PrivateKey.Sequence[j]}. element: {ciphertextElement}");
                }
            }
        }

        // Copy BitArray data to byte[] array and return
        var (quotient1, remainder1) = Math.DivRem(plaintextBits.Length, BitsPerByte);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[quotient1 + (remainder1 == 0 ? 0 : 1)];
        plaintextBits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        return bytes;
    }


    public static KnapsackCryptosystem Create(
        IReadOnlyList<int> sequence, int m, int w)
    {
        if (sequence.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Sequence must be non-empty.", 
                nameof(sequence));
        }
        int sum = sequence[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < sequence.Count; i++)
        {
            if (sequence[i] <= sum)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "Not a superincreasing sequence.", 
                    nameof(sequence));
            }
            sum += sequence[i];
        }
        if (m <= sum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                nameof(m), 
                "m must be greater than the sum of the sequence.");
        }

        if (MathHelpers.Gcd(m, w) != 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "w must be coprime to m.", 
                nameof(w));
        }

        IReadOnlyList<int> publicSequence = GeneratePublicSequence(sequence, m, w);

        return new KnapsackCryptosystem(
            new PublicKeyInfo(publicSequence),
            new PrivateKeyInfo(sequence, m, w)
        );
    }

    private static IReadOnlyList<int> GeneratePublicSequence(
        IReadOnlyList<int> sequence, int m, int w) => (
            from item in sequence
            select (w * item) % m)
            .ToList()
            .AsReadOnly();    // Multiply each item in the sequence by w and mod by m


    public readonly record struct PublicKeyInfo(IReadOnlyList<int> Sequence);

    // M is the modulus greater than sum of public sequence
    // W is the integer coprime to M
    private readonly record struct PrivateKeyInfo(IReadOnlyList<int> Sequence, int M, int W);

    private KnapsackCryptosystem(PublicKeyInfo publicKey, PrivateKeyInfo privateKey)
    {
        PublicKey = publicKey;
        PrivateKey = privateKey;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The individual sizes of each `BigInteger` is lost when it is converted to `byte[]`"_ - in your result stream you just need to prefix every serialized `BigInteger` with a length instead of just concatenating the byte arrays. See an example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JgHbPs)

Comment: You could use something like Protobuf.net to do your binary serialization for you.  See e.g. [Protobuf-net surrogate class for BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45730434).

Comment: Or use a binary serializer that supports `BigInteger` natively, without any surrogates. In the provided link I just mentioned [my serializer](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries#binary-serialization) in a pair of comments but [here](https://docs.kgysoft.net/corelibraries/html/T_KGySoft_Serialization_Binary_BinarySerializationFormatter.htm) you can find more details about it.

Comment: Do you really need to use `BigInteger`? Sample implementation here does it with basic `int` it seems https://github.com/Childcity/Cipher/blob/master/TheKnapsackProblemCipher.cs